# Selenium - grabbing an element from an unordered list

Tags: html, selenium

I'm not very familiar with html, but wanted to build a simple webscraper with selenium. I'm trying to access the comments on reddit.com and am having a ton of trouble actually picking out each element. The part I'm looking at is here: 
[image]

I've tried too many things to even list here, none of it works. The one thing that perplexes me is that I used FirePath to copy the Xpath and it still didn't work. (it came back empty).The Xpath is spits out is `.//*[@id='thing_t3_5khd75']/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a`

Comment: Show code you use. Also clarify what output you want to get: number of comments for each post or actual comments text for specific post?

Answer (score 1):

Several posts on the top of page are hidden, so if to use `element.text` you'll get empty string. Also I advice you not to use `FirePath`, but to create [your own `XPath` instead](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) to make your selector more flexible

To get actual values you can use (I suppose you use `Python` as I checked your profile :) ):

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="bylink comments may-blank"]')
comments = {}
for post in posts:
    comments[post.get_attribute('href')] = post.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

The output of `comments` will be something like

```
{'https://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/5kfw6w/cheetahs_heading_towards_extinction_as_population/': '1904 comments',
 'https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/5kh5q4/a_cutting_board_made_of_walnut_white_oak_maple/': '217 comments',...}
```

Comment: I tried to modify that to get something like the title using xpath and it didn't work. My Xpath was: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="title may-blank loggedin outbound srTagged"]')`. I suppose I could just use regular expressions, but I'd prefer to do it without.

Comment: Do you want to change code to get something like `{"post_1_title": "100 comments", "post_2_title": "200 comments", ...}`?

Comment: No, I was just saying if I try to grab the title, it doesn't work. Here's a picture: http://imgur.com/a/meaR3. The title is right below in plain text.

Comment: You want to get just text like `"My cat only has 3..."`? And all other titles?

Comment: yes, but I'm just using this as an example so I can figure out how to find xpaths myself. The link you sent helps, bu I still (apparently) don't understand.

Comment: Class names could changes depending on some conditions. Actually `title may-blank loggedin outbound srTagged` means that `CSS` properties from classes `title`, `may-blank`, `loggedin`... were applied to element at the moment you check page source, but some of them could be  removed from this **compound** class name. Now (when I check) class name for same title is `"title may-blank outbound"`, so `"title may-blank loggedin outbound srTagged"` is not applicable in `XPath` anymore. This http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf should also be helpful